# exposing webapi to thirdparty which accepts json and/or parameters using Golang

Tags: go

I started learning GoLang recently. My aim is to expose a webapi. This should be able to accept a json object and should respond with another json object. I am not finding enough resources to learn how to get this working. I really appreciate any help in this regard. A piece of my code is like below.

```
func HelloService(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
io.WriteString(res,"Welcome to service")
}

func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloService)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080",nil)
    http.HandleFunc("/saveuser", saveUser)
}

func saveUser(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    ConfigurationRepository.SaveUser(User) //I want to receive an User    object when this service is being consumed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An http package that wraps "net/http" will be helpful. Examples:

https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful

https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin

Here is a simple service to get you started:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/emicklei/go-restful"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type User struct {
    Name string
}

func postOne(req *restful.Request, resp *restful.Response) {
    newUser := new(User)
    err := req.ReadEntity(newUser)
    if err != nil {
        resp.WriteErrorString(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }

    log.Printf("new user: '%v'", newUser)
}

func main() {
    ws := new(restful.WebService)
    ws.Path("/users")
    ws.Consumes(restful.MIME_JSON)
    ws.Produces(restful.MIME_JSON)

    ws.Route(ws.POST("").To(postOne).
        Param(ws.BodyParameter("User", "A User").DataType("main.User")))

   restful.Add(ws)

  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Here is a curl to test the service by posting a single user:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "localhost:8080/users" -d '{"name": "Joe"}'
```

Comment: Hi Niko, Thanks for your reply. All methods of instance ws (path, consumes, produces, Route, POST, To, Param, BodyParameter, DataType) are not being recognized however there was no error while creating ws. Same issue with the req. All methods are not being recognized. What could be the issue

Comment: No issues after restarting IDE.

Comment: Good to hear. Which IDE are you using?